# Getting and setting priority value for a parent process and child process

Tags: perl

I have a perl script which will create a child process. I need to get the priority(nice) value for these two process(parent and child)

I can get the pid of both parent and child process as below:

```
$parentPID = $$;
$childPID = fork();
```

How to get the priority values for these process in perl script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check [`getpriority()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/getpriority.html) where first parameter for PID is `PRIO_PROCESS` (you can use [`BSD::Resource`](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/JHI/BSD-Resource-1.2907/Resource.pm) to import this constant or just use zero instead)

Reading current PID priority, and setting new one,

```
nice -7 perl -E'say getpriority(0,$$); setpriority(0,$$,9); say getpriority(0,$$)'
```

output

```
7
9
```

Comment: I like the return to your old name.  =)

Comment: @Miller Hi, I was undercover for some time as Russian fighter jet. :) It looks US are making great efforts recently to provoke conflict here in Europe.

Answer (score 2):

use the [Forks::Super](https://metacpan.org/pod/Forks::Super#os_priority) CPAN module. Example:

```
$pid = fork { os_priority => 10 };   # like nice(1) on Un*x
```

if you don't want to use a CPAN module, [setpriority](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/setpriority.html) function sets the current priority for a process, a process group, or a user.

Comment: I cannot install any CPAN module and can work on only STANDARD perl modules.